# How to insert data through form:input path with model attribute inside another model Spring Mybatis

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I'm facing the problem when using Spring/Mybatis to insert data through form:input path, I using 2 class/table and I want to insert data into both(User and DetailUserJapan). This is my source:

Class User:

```
public class User {     
private Long user_id;           
private DetailUserJapan detail_user_japan_id;        
private String login_name;
private String password;
private String full_name;
private String full_name_kana;
private String email;
private String tel;    
private Date birthday;    
private boolean rule;    
private String salt;
// getter and setter
}
```

Class DetailUserJapan:

```
public class DetailUserJapan {
private Long detail_user_japan_id;  
private Set<User> user_id = new HashSet<User>(); 
private Date start_date;
private Date end_date;
private int total;
// setter and getter
}
```

Controller class:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/showFormAddUser", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView showFormAddNewUser(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, 
        ModelMap model) throws ServletException, IOException {

    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("add_user");        
    User createUser = new User();

    model.addAttribute("createUser", createUser);       
    return mav;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/addUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String submitAddNewUser(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        @RequestParam("groupSelected") Integer groupSelected,
        @RequestParam("japanMasterSelected") String japanMasterSelected,

        @ModelAttribute("createUser") User createUser, BindingResult result, ModelMap model) throws SQLException, IOException {

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "add_user";         
    }

    GroupMaster myGroupMaster = userService.getGroupById(groupSelected);        
    JapanMaster myJapanMaster = userService.getJapanMasterById(japanMasterSelected); 

    createUser.setGroup_id(myGroupMaster);      
    createUser.setCode_level(myJapanMaster);    

    userService.insertUser(createUser);

    return "redirect:/";
}
```

Mapper class:

```
public interface UserMapper {

@Insert("INSERT INTO users(group_id, code_level, login_name, password, full_name,"
        + "full_name_kana, birthday, email, tel, rule, salt) VALUES"
        + "(#{group_id.group_id}, #{code_level.code_level}, #{login_name},#{password}, #{full_name}, #{full_name_kana},"
        + "#{birthday}, #{email}, #{tel}, #{rule}, #{salt})")
@Options(useGeneratedKeys=true, keyProperty="id", flushCache=true, keyColumn="id")
public void insertUser(User user);
```

}

add_user.jsp file

```
<form:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/addUser.html" method="POST" modelAttribute="createUser" commandName="createUser">

<span>login name<span class="required">*</span></span>
<form:input type="text" path="login_name" class="input-field" />

<span>password<span class="required">*</span></span>                    
<form:input type="text" path="password" class="input-field" />
<br>

<span>full name<span class="required">*</span></span>
<form:input type="text" path="full_name" class="input-field" />
<br>

<span>birthday<span class="required">*</span></span>                    
<form:input type="text" path="birthday" class="input-field" />
<br>

<span>email<span class="required">*</span></span>                   
<form:input type="text" path="email" class="input-field" />
<br>

<span>tel<span class="required">*</span></span>         
<form:input type="text" path="tel" class="input-field" />
<br>

<span>Salt<span class="required">*</span></span>            
<form:input type="text" path="salt" class="input-field" />

<span>End Date<span class="required">*</span></span>
<form:input type="text" path="detail_user_japan_id.end_date" class="input-field" />
<br>

<span>Total<span class="required">*</span></span>
<form:input type="text" path="detail_user_japan_id.total" class="input-field" />
<br>

<label>
<span></span>                   
<input type="Submit" value="Add new user" />    
</label>
```

When I input data in form page and click submit, I can insert data into 2 table normal, but only 2 textbox is 'end_date' and 'total' is can not insert, it seem null or empty data

```
<span>End Date<span class="required">*</span></span>
<form:input type="text" path="detail_user_japan_id.end_date" class="input-field" />
<br>

<span>Total<span class="required">*</span></span>
<form:input type="text" path="detail_user_japan_id.total" class="input-field" />
<br>
```

How to fix the problem ?

Comment: MyBatis executes SQLs just as you write them. These answers may be informative : [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23921307/1261766), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4788981/1261766).

Comment: Useful information for me, thank @ave

Comment: Could you provide a small reproduce project ?

Comment: Hi @KazukiShimizu: i will share sample project on google driver or github